# Remove menu pages only for non admin

Tags: admin-menu

I have this method in my plugin, I want to avoid that the users that are not administrator can see some menus in the dashboard. I know that this can be achived using the roles, but in my case I will have just another one account that will have author permissions.

```php
    public function remove_default_menu_pages()
    {
        if( !is_user_admin() && is_user_logged_in() ){
            remove_menu_page('edit.php');
            remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
            remove_menu_page('themes.php');
        }
    }
```

I've noticed that also if I'm logged as an administrator, I'm not able to see the menus, in the code I've used the `is_user_admin()` function so I was supposing that the check was done before removing the menu pages. Is there any reason that WP have this beahviour?

Comment: If you don't want users to be able to edit posts, comments, or change themes then don't give them a user role that lets them do those things. Removing the menu page is not sufficient. See https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/ for a list of user roles and capabilities.

Comment: I need to have at least one user that will manage some CPT for a catalogue, this is why I want to do this choice.

Comment: So create custom capabilities when registering the post type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#capability_type Then create a user role with just those capabilities. Make sure when you're asking a question to ask about your _actual_ problem. You wanted to know how to have a user that can only edit one post type, but then question you asked was focused on a specific solution that was inappropriate. I suggest updating your question to describe your real problem, then you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: My question is focused on the problem that is why `is_user_admin()` will not work as expected. I will follow your suggestion, but at the moment I need to understand why the function have this strange beahviour

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_admin/

Comment: My mistake into the function implementation, probably I need to use `current_user_can()` to check if an user is administrator or not. Thank you for the tips. Please leave a reply so I can mark the question as solved.